# Possible inconsistency between Help Center and close reason regarding programming tools

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons, help-center

According to Help Center's [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page

> but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But then there is this closing reason

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Don't these two points contradict each other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We are not here to **find** you a tool.

But if you have a question ***about*** a tool -- Like Eclipse, Netbeans, Putty, Lemonade making, etc, we will be **glad** to help!

I see no real contradiction there.